# Sass ampersand and two parents together in mixin?

Tags: css, sass

I'm faced with the task of theming the site. I found a suitable mixin. Everything would work well, if not for the mixin for events. It turns out that I need to do something, so that if the topic's mixin is invoked in the mixin of events, then the class did not go cascade, but substituted for the topic class, the .no-touchevents class on the html tag.

[image: Example]

Ideally, that would be so on the output:

```css
.card {
  color: #fff;
}
.t-dark .card {
  color: #000;
}
.no-touchevents .card:hover {
  color: #000;
}
.t-dark.no-touchevents .card:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Is including the `.no-touchevents` necessary in the definition? For example, is there a rule for `.t-dark .card:hover`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hacky (or maybe a lot hacky) but by adding an additional parameter to the themify mixin and building our selector manually, you can achieve the output you're looking for.

```
$themes: (
    dark: (
        colorDark: #000,
        colorLight: #fff
    )
);
@mixin on-event() {
  .no-touchevents &:hover {
      @content;
  }
}
@mixin themify($themes, $flat: ' ') { // Add a parameter to separate by default
    @each $theme, $map in $themes {
      @at-root .t-#{$theme}#{$flat}#{&} {  // Build our selector manually
          $theme-map: () !global;
          @each $key, $submap in $map {
              $value: map-get(map-get($themes, $theme), '#{$key}');
              $theme-map: map-merge($theme-map, ($key: $value)) !global;
          }
          @content;
          $theme-map: null !global;
      }
    }
}

@function themed($key) {
    @return map-get($theme-map, $key);
}

.card {
  color: #fff;
  @include themify($themes) {
      color: themed('colorDark')
    } 
  @include on-event() {
    color: #000;
    @include themify($themes, '') { // Tell themify not to separate selectors
      color: themed('colorLight')
    } 
  }
}
```